# convert string into datetime object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to send `Date` object for current date to my back end from javascript

What I am doing is

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var dateString = currentDate.getMonth() + "-"
  + currentDate.getDate() + "-" + currentDate.getFullYear() + " "
  + currentDate.getHours() + ":" + currentDate.getMinutes() + ":"
  + currentDate.getSeconds();
var newDate = new Date(Date.parse(dateString));
```

But it is saying *Invalid Date* to `newDate`.

I have to send 3-10-2013 6:10:25 PM as datetime object to backend.

Comment: Why wont you just use `setYear()`, `setMonth()`, etc.

Comment: Works fine for me -> http://jsfiddle.net/5ne6D/

Comment: @adeneo Firefox (19.0.2 and 20.0, OSX) does give the error

Comment: What browser does this not work in? Btw, `Date.parse(currentDate.toString())` will always work

Comment: When you say backend, are you saying that you are trying to send a date back to the server? Do you need it to be in a time stamp format?

Comment: @adeneo not even running.

Comment: @Kalpers I want to send DateTime object to server.

Comment: @vaibhavshah - works for me **in chrome** is probably more accurate. Date.parse is implented differently in browsers, and as such sucks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = new Date(),
    utcYear = currentDate.getUTCFullYear(),
    utcMonth = ('0' + currenctDate.getUTCMonth()).slice(-2),
    utcDay = ('0' + currentDate.getUTCDate()).slice(-2),
    fullDateString = utcMonth.toString() + '/' + utcDay.toString() + '/' + utcYear.toString();
```

Same principle if you want to get the time part as well.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of putting `-` in between the month/date and date/year, just put spaces.

```
var currentDate = new Date(),
    dateString = currentDate.getMonth() + " " + 
                  currentDate.getDate() + " " + 
              currentDate.getFullYear() + " " + 
                 currentDate.getHours() + ":" + 
               currentDate.getMinutes() + ":" + 
               currentDate.getSeconds(),
    newDate = new Date(dateString);

console.log(newDate)
```

Comment: you should add comma after `getDate()`, this is the proper format to dateString: `new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @JanTuroň there are plenty of ways to plug in numbers and get the correct date. The document you links gives at least 3 that I saw at a glance. Based on that you CAN use month number, vice month name. and you don't have to include the comma after the date.

Comment: indeed, there's quite a lot possibilities - if the browsers follow the RFC 2822 specification: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#page-14